# Open another form on submission in AMP HTML

Tags: javascript, forms, amp-html

I am creating a contact form using AMP HTML.

After receiving the success response on `action-xhr` submission, I want to open another form for OTP verification. Verification url comes in the success response only.

I know that nested forms are against HTML validation, so another form inside the success template won't be possible at all. Any other technique/method through which I can achieve this, apart from redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine AMP's `submit-success` event, the `show` action, and the `hidden` attribute to reveal a hidden form.

```
<form 
  method="post"
  action-xhr="/form/echo-json/post"
  target="_blank"
  on="submit-success:form2.show"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>

<!-- ... -->

<form id="form2" hidden>
  <p>But wait! There's more!</p>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

If you want to bind something to the success response, you'll need to add `amp-bind` and use `on="submit-success:AMP.setState({property: event.response.property})"`

Comment: Still one problem I am facing is creating dynamic action-xhr as action-xhr cannot be bind. action-xhr is stored in the response from first contact. I am able to set state on that but not able to create xhr url for the second form dynamically. Any help on that?

Comment: Glad I could help : ) Hmm this is a different question. Yes, it would be convenient to bind to the action-xhr value, but maybe you could bind to the of a hidden input in the second form `<input type="hidden" name="secondAction" value="" [value]="boundVariable" />`, and then use that form value on the server to know to perform the correct behavior.

Comment: Yeah. Doing that only. However added a feature enhancement request on their official repo